# Writing, updating and reading lists to and from external files with user inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I looked at various solutions using csv, txt,py files, but could not accomplish quite what I want, which is:

- I would like keep a list of integers in a separate file
- append new entries to the list through user input to that separate file
- and read them back the updated version as a list, in int form so calculations can be made, from that file.

I've been trying through the following code;

```
print('Enter the result of your last reading=')
newReading = input()
reading = [int(newReading)]
with open('avg.py', 'a') as f:
    f.write('reading = ' . reading)

from avg.py import reading as my_list
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please see [ask] and [mcve].  This question should contain sample input data and desired output based on that sample.  Also you could show what you have tried, and what problem you are having. SO is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
filename = "avg.txt"

while True:

    new_reading = input("\nEnter the result of your last reading: ")

    with open(filename, 'a') as f_obj:
        f_obj.write(new_reading)

    with open(filename) as f_obj:
        contents = f_obj.read()

    reading = list(contents)
    print(reading)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3 read_write_files.py 
>
> Enter the result of your last reading: 1
> ['1']
>
> Enter the result of your last reading: 2
> ['1', '2']
>
> Enter the result of your last reading: 3
> ['1', '2', '3']
> ```

**Comments**

This route involves using a second piece of code to open the file, and then I read the data and store it into `contents`.  After that can turn the contents into a list using `list(contents)`.

You can from here work with the list `reading` other than just printing it.  Also I would think about turning this into a `if` `else` loop and create some condition like `q to quit` etc to end the program.

Something like this:

```
filename = "avg.txt"

while True:

    new_reading = input("\nEnter the result of your last reading" \
        "('q' to quit): ")

    if new_reading == "q":
        break

    else:
        with open(filename, 'a') as f_obj:
            f_obj.write(new_reading)

        with open(filename) as f_obj:
            contents = f_obj.read()

        reading = list(contents)

        print(reading)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is something that I can build on!

Comment: @Y.Bayar Your welcome. Also I would recommend Python Crash Course which covers this very clearly, along with many other topics.